# Stuck formulating an adjacency constraint with pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, sparse-matrix, linear-programming, integer-programming

I'm trying to assign `attributes` into a 3 x 3 matrix based on an adjacency constraint, but I'm stuck formulating the adjacency constraint. I keep thinking I've got the answer, then when I try it the result isn't as expected.

So, `element`s are pre-arranged into an `element_map` which is a 9 x 17 matrix. Each of the 9 `element`s has 17 `attributes`, which are always zero or one.

The `element`s are in fixed positions in the 3 x 3 matrix:

```
[[0, 3, 6
  1, 4, 7
  2, 5, 8]]
```

For example, the `element` at index `2` in the `element_map` is fixed at position `(2,0)` in the 3 x 3 matrix. And `(2,0)` is adjacent to `(1,0), (1,1), (2,1)`.

The constraints are:

1. each `place` can have at most 4 `attribute`s assigned to it (**done**)
2. each `place` must have one or more `attributes` assigned to it (**done**)
3. the selected `attribute`s for each `place` must be equal to zero  (**done**)
4. **Adjacency constraint**: Explained below with an example (**need help**)

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import numpy as np


"""
fit elements into matrix based on adjacency rules
"""


class Element:

    """a convenience to hold the rows of attribute values"""
    def __init__(self, row):
        self.attributes = tuple(row)

    def attribute(self, idx):
        return self.attributes[idx]

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.attributes)


class Position:
 
    """a convenience for (x, y) positions that must have equality & hash defined for consistency"""
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'({self.x}, {self.y})'

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, self.y))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Position):
            return (self.x, self.y) == (other.x, other.y)
        return False

# each 'row' corresponds to an element
# each 'column' corresponds to an attribute of the various elements
# here, each element has attributes which are always 0 or 1
element_map = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                        [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                        [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])



print(element_map, 'map')
print (element_map.shape)

matrix_a_rows = 3
matrix_a_cols = 3
matrix_a = np.zeros((matrix_a_rows, matrix_a_cols))

mask = np.arange(1,(matrix_a_rows*matrix_a_cols)+1).reshape(matrix_a_cols, matrix_a_rows).T


def get_element(position):
    #get the element vector at a position
    x,y =position.x, position.y
    idx = mask[x,y]-1
    return idx #return 0-indexed element idx

def adj_xy(mat, p: Position):
    x, y = p.x, p.y
    res = []
    rows = len(mat) - 1
    cols = len(mat[0]) - 1
    for i in range(x - 1, x + 2):
        for j in range(y - 1, y + 2):
            if all((0 <= i <= rows, 0 <= j <= cols, (i, j) != (x, y))):
                res.append(Position(i, j))
    return res

# SET UP ILP
m = pyo.ConcreteModel('matrix_fitter')

# SETS

elements = np.array([np.array(row) for row in element_map])


m.P = pyo.Set(initialize=[Position(x, y) for x in range(len(matrix_a)) for y in range(len(matrix_a[0]))],
              doc='positions')

m.A = pyo.Set(initialize=list(range(len(element_map[0]))), doc='attribute')

    
# VARS
# place element e in position p based on attribute a being 0...
m.place = pyo.Var(m.P, m.A, domain=pyo.Binary, doc='place')

# OBJ:  minimize attributes assigned to each position
m.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=pyo.sum_product(m.place), sense=pyo.minimize)

#each place must have 4 or fewer attributes assigned to it
m.attr_constraint = pyo.ConstraintList()
for p in m.P:
    s = 0
    for a in m.A:
        s += m.place[p,a]
    m.attr_constraint.add(s <= 4)

#each place must have one or more attributes assigned to it
m.enzyme_constraint = pyo.ConstraintList()
for p in m.P:
    s = 0
    for a in m.A:
        s += m.place[p,a]
    m.attr_constraint.add(s >= 1)


#the selected attribute for each position must be equal to zero 
m.cut_constraint = pyo.ConstraintList()
for p in m.P:
    e_idx = get_element(p)
    element = elements[e_idx]
    for i,a in enumerate(m.A):
        if element[i] == 1:
            m.cut_constraint.add(m.place[p,a] == 0)

#adjacency constraint
#doesn't work as expected
#This is where I need help...
m.adjacency_constraint = pyo.ConstraintList()
for p in m.P:
    plate_element = elements[get_element(p)]
    neighbor_positions = adj_xy(matrix_a, p)
    print (p, 'place')
    for i,a in enumerate(m.A):
        s = 0
        for j,aa in enumerate(m.A):
            for neighbor in neighbor_positions:
                neighbor_element = elements[get_element(neighbor)]
                neighbor_element_attribute = neighbor_element[i]
                s += m.place[neighbor,aa]*neighbor_element_attribute


        m.adjacency_constraint.add(s >= len(neighbor_positions)*m.place[p,a])


solver = pyo.SolverFactory('cbc')

results = solver.solve(m, tee=True)

print(results, 'results')
if results.solver.termination_condition == pyo.TerminationCondition.optimal:
    for idx in m.place.index_set():
        if m.place[idx].value == 1:
            s = 0
            att = idx[1]
            
            neighs = adj_xy(matrix_a, idx[0])
            for i in neighs:
                place_element = elements[get_element(i)]
                s += place_element[att]

            print(idx, 'idx', s)
    if pyo.value(m.obj) == matrix_a_rows * matrix_a_cols:
        # all positions were filled
        print('success!')
    else:
        print(f'the number of elements that can be placed is {pyo.value(m.obj)} / {matrix_a_rows * matrix_a_cols}')

else:
    print('Problem with model...see results')
print (element_map)
```

With an `element_map` that looks like this:

```
[[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]]
```

...the result I get is:

```
((0, 0), 0) idx 2 
((0, 0), 1) idx 2 
((0, 0), 9) idx 2 
((0, 0), 16) idx 3
((0, 1), 5) idx 2 
((0, 1), 6) idx 2 
((0, 1), 9) idx 4 
((0, 2), 3) idx 2 
((1, 0), 1) idx 2 
((1, 0), 5) idx 2 
((1, 1), 4) idx 7 
((1, 1), 15) idx 4
((1, 2), 1) idx 2 
((2, 0), 0) idx 3 
((2, 1), 3) idx 4 
((2, 2), 7) idx 2
```

The format is: `((x,y), selected_attribute)`. `(x,y)` is the coordinate in the 3 x 3 matrix and `selected_attribute` is one of the selected `attribute`s for that `place`.

**Example**

Let's consider the `element` at `(1,1)`, because it is adjacent to all other `places`. The data for this `element` is:

```
[1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
```

The selected `attribute`s for `(1,1)` in the result are `4` and `15`. Taking a look at the `element_map`, `attribute` `4` is a good choice for this `element`, because all except for the second-to-last `element` have a value of `1` for that `attribute`. The other selected `attribute`, `15`, is not good, however, because the `attribute` at index `15` is a zero for the second-to-last element. For the `element` at `(1,1)`, `attribute` `4` would work in combination with the following `attribute` indices: `3 or 9 or 16`, because for the second-to-last `element`, those `attribute` values are all `1`.

**Adjacency Constraint Definition**

So the adjacency constraint should be: assign `attribute`s to a `place` such that all adjacent `place`s have at least one value of `1` among all the selected `attribute`s. And it is a minimization problem, so overall I want the minimum number of `attribute`s assigned to each `place` that meet the constraints.

I hope this was clear, please comment if there's something I can clarify; thanks for reading!

Comment: Maybe I'm getting lost on attribute/element/place, but...  You say attribute 4 works at (1, 1), but that attribute is is zero which contradicts your 3rd constraint?

Comment: @AirSquid thanks. I was hoping you'd take a look at this! I meant zero-indexed attribute 4, so it's the zero in parens: `[1 1 0 1 (0) 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]`

Comment: :).  Yeah, I see the zero-indexing, but your #3 constraint at the top says that number must not be zero, and it is... ?

Comment: Aside from that, is the constraint you are trying to do to assign enough attributes to each `place` such that all adjacent places are referenced (with a 1) by at least one of the assigned attributes?

Comment: I see now, thanks for catching that -- my mistake. I edited the question. Yes that is a much more succinct way of stating the adjacency constraint I'm aiming for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a couple of components....

First, you need an indexed list of which places are adjacent to each place.  If you are using your single-digit indexing system, that would be something like:

```
neighbors = { 0: [1, 3, 4], 1: [0, 3, 4, 5, 2], ...}
```

these indices will be the basis of summation for a constraint to ensure coverage.  Something like in pseudocode/untested:

```
def cover(model, base, neighbor):
    return sum(model.place[base, a] * element_map[neighbor, a] for a in attributes) >= 1

# make some flat list of all the possible base-neighbor combos...
bn = [(b, n) for b in neighbors for n in neighbors[b] ]

model.neighbor_coverage = pyo.Constraint(bn, rule=cover)
```

Basically stating that for each base-neighbor combo, you must select some attribute with `place` that generates coverage.

Try to see if you can get that spinning.  If stuck, comment back!

Comment: looks like this worked.. I had a feeling I needed an index like this. much obliged